# mongoid uninitialized constant Point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I hear about and try to implement those libraries [mongoid-geospatial](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid-geospatial)

But they all mention this class `Point` which is undefined for me. What am I missing ?

I am adding a geo concern to my models with ActiveSupport::Concern

```
module Mappable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Mongoid::Geospatial

    field :coordinates, type: Point, spatial: true
    spatial_scope :coordinates
```

> uninitialized constant Mappable::Point (NameError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resolve it from the [proper namespace](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid-geospatial/blob/master/lib/mongoid/geospatial/fields/point.rb).

```
field :coordinates, type: ::Mongoid::Geospatial::Point, spatial: true
```

The example from the docs works since they are declaring a class which does not create a new module nesting. In your case however Ruby will try to resolve `Point` from the current module (`Mapping`) even if you have included `Mongoid::Geospatial`.